# How to build project so that only index.html is at the root?

Tags: angular, build

Is there a way to build for production and only have the `index.html` file at the root of the dist folder? The goal is to simplify the proxies I am using. All assets like the `main.js`, `polyfills.js`, etc would be under a specific folder which means all requests made to the root would be proxied to my `index.html`. Having to split requests such as `https://example.com/specific-page` and `https://example.com/main.js` in 2 proxies makes things more complex for me.

Those are the options in `angular.json` inside the `build` section :

```
"options": {
    "outputPath": "dist",
    "index": "src/index.html",
    "main": "src/main.ts",
    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
    "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
    "assets": [
         "src/favicon.ico",
         "src/robots.txt",
         "src/assets",
         "src/proxy.json"
     ],
     "styles": [
         "src/styles.scss"
     ],
     "scripts": [],
     "es5BrowserSupport": true
}
```

**TLDR** can I output the main, polyfills and tsConfig files to another folder while keeping the `index.html` at the root of the dist folder?

Answer (score 0):

There is more better way) You should build your app with base href argument.
For example is you app path: https://example.com/specific-page

```
ng build --base-href /specific-page/
```

And all your bundles and etc will get from https://example.com/specific-page/bundle.js

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that doesn't work for what I want to accomplish. Using the `--base-href` argument changes the base location of everything and I still have the same problem afterwards. `https://example.com/specific-page` is meant to be a page available to the user. Another example could be `https://example.com/blog`, I would not want my blog being accessible by doing `https://example.com/base-href/blog`. **But yes**, I would want my `bundle.js` to be available at `https://example.com/other-folder-than-root/bundle.js`. I hope this clarifies things.